# Python regular expression with or and re.search

Tags: python, regex

Say I have two types of strings:

```
str1 = 'NUM-140 A Thing: Foobar Analysis NUM-140'
str2 = 'NUM-140 Foobar Analysis NUM-140'
```

For both of these, I want to match `'Foobar'` (which could be anything). I have tried the following:

```
m = re.compile('((?<=Thing: ).+(?= Analysis))|((?<=\d ).+(?= Analysis))')

ind1 = m.search(str1).span()
match1 = str1[ind1[0]:ind1[1]]

ind2 = m.search(str2).span()
match2 = str2[ind2[0]:ind2[1]]
```

However, match1 comes out to `'A Thing: Foobar'`, which seems to be the match for the second pattern, not the first. Applied individually, (pattern 1 to `str1` and pattern 2 to `str2`, without the `|`), both patterns match `'Foobar'`. I expected this, then, to stop when matched by the first pattern. This doesn't seem to be the case. What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that in the 7th position (while consuming the character '0') the regex can already do the match.

Comment: Oh, that's right. The first match it finds _is_ with the second pattern. Somehow missed that.

Comment: did you try `re.compile(".*Foobar.*")`

Comment: That won't work. That'll match all surrounding text too, and is specific to the phrase `'Foobar'`.  Foobar is a placeholder for anything, really, and I want to extract only `'Foobar'` itself or whatever there is in place of `'Foobar'`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation,

> As the target string is scanned, REs separated by '|' are tried from left to right. When one pattern completely matches, that branch is accepted. This means that once A matches, B will not be tested further, even if it would produce a longer overall match. In other words, the '|' operator is never greedy.

But the behavior seems to be different:

```
import re

THING = r'(?<=Thing: )(?P<THING>.+)(?= Analysis)'
NUM = r'(?<=\d )(?P<NUM>.+)(?= Analysis)'
MIXED = THING + '|' + NUM

str1 = 'NUM-140 A Thing: Foobar Analysis NUM-140'
str2 = 'NUM-140 Foobar Analysis NUM-140'

print(re.match(THING, str1))
# <... match='Foobar'>
print(re.match(NUM, str1))
# <... match='A Thing: Foobar'>
print(re.match(MIXED, str1))
# <... match='A Thing: Foobar'>
```

We would expect that because THING matches 'Foobar', the MIXED pattern would get that 'Foobar' and quit searching. (as per the documentation)

Because it is not working as documented, the solution has to rely on Python's `or` short-circuiting:

```
print(re.search(THING, str1) or re.search(NUM, str1))
# <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(17, 23), match='Foobar'>

print(re.search(THING, str2) or re.search(NUM, str2))
# <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 14), match='Foobar'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interestingly enough, reading over that documentation it seems the behavior _might_ actually follow it, just the wording is ambiguous. It's not specified what "as the string is scanned" really means, so it could be checking the RE's left to right _per character_ or some subtlety like that, which would lead to the behavior we're seeing. (similar to what @horcrux's comment on my original question was suggesting). In any case, i think `or` might be the cleanest way to achieve the intended behavior, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use named groups, eg `(?P<name>...)` you'll be able to debug easier. But note the docs for span.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.span

> span([group]) For MatchObject m, return the 2-tuple (m.start(group),
>   m.end(group)). Note that if group did not contribute to the match,
>   this is (-1, -1). group defaults to zero, the entire match.

You're not passing in the group number.

Why are you using span anyway? Just use `m.search(str1).groups()` or similar